# Excel VBA: activate the cell after the last one in a column

Tags: vba, excel

Silly question: how do I go to the cell right after the last non-blank cell in column ? I can't figure it out for the life of me.

I've tried something akin to: `Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown) + 1).Activate` (A1 is blank) and `Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown + 1)).Activate` , but it errors out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count,1).End(xlup).Offset(1).Activate
```

---

NOTE:  One should avoid `.Activate` and `.Select`  These slow down code, but should directly use the reference.

See [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more information.